# How to group by name variable in TeX using RMarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown, tex

This is what I have so far:

```
`r Name`
    
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
       \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Code} & \textbf{Amount} \\
       `r id` & `r code` & \$ `r amount` 
    \end{tabular}
    
    
    
    \begin{flushright} \textbf{SUBTOTAL: \$ `r subtotal`} \\
    \textbf{FEE: \$ `r fee`} \\
    \textbf{TOTAL: \$ `r total`} \end{flushright}
```

The result should look something like this:

[image]

My result only return one row but the totals are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use ktable.

```
kable(table, "latex")
```